# What does "forty-four tears hell out of a man" mean

Tags: expressions

In "East of Eden" the Sheriff tells Kate that Adam Trask is "a forty-four tears hell out of a man". Is that an expression in English? I've never encountered it before, neither has Google it seems.

Comment: A "44" is a bullet.

Comment: So-called because it was .44 inches in diameter.  Wikipedia says the modern-day version  it is actually .429 inches (10.9 mm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From page 71 [https://readbooksnovel.com/east-of-eden/page-71-1008/]:

> “I want peace in this county, and I mean all kinds of peace, and that
> means people getting to sleep at night. Now I haven’t met your
> husband,” he said, and she knew he noticed the slight movement of her
> tightening muscles. “I hear he’s a very nice man. I hear also that
> he’s pretty hard hit.” He looked into her eyes for a moment. “Don’t
> you want to know how bad you shot him?”
>
> “Yes,” she said.
>
> “Well, he’s going to get well—smashed his shoulder, but he’s going to
> get well. That Chink is taking pretty good care of him. Course I don’t
> think he’ll lift anything with his left arm for quite a spell. A
> forty-four tears hell out of a man. If the Chink hadn’t come back he’d
> of bled to death, and you’d be staying with me in the jail.”

So she shot her husband with a forty-four handgun.

Comment: Haha, thanks, for some reason I was stuck thinking "tears" as in the product of crying and that made absolutely no sense.